# Can't add a action to menu item

Tags: swift, cocoa

Why can't I add an action? When I push the button **setDefault** or the **clearText** (code in AppDelegate) pop up an error: 
[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyyWG.png)

My story board:

[Story Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcx3S.png)

[My menu items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqWQX.png)

My ViewController:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Lable: NSTextField!


    @IBAction func setButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let value = textField.stringValue
        Lable.stringValue = value
    }

}
```

My AppDelegate :

```
    @IBAction func setDefault(_ sender: Any) {
        let defaultVar:String = "Default"
        Label.stringValue = defaultVar
    }

    @IBAction func clearText(_ sender: Any) {
        let clear:String = " "
        Label.stringValue = clear
    }
```

Comment: What is Lable? :O

Comment: Label is the name of my label in the store board

Comment: `@IBOutlet weak var Lable: NSTextField!`

Comment: You most probably did not connect your label outlet in interface builder. Check that you have `@IBOutlet weak var Lable: NSTextField!` connected. It would also be helpful to read some naming conventions for apps written in Swift to keep your code concise.

Comment: NSTextField is not a Label...

Comment: So what I should add?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel

Answer (score 1):

Move both actions into the **view controller**, change the sender to `NSMenuItem` and adjust `Lable` (by the way please name properties with starting lowercase letter)

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Lable: NSTextField!


    @IBAction func setButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let value = textField.stringValue
        Lable.stringValue = value
    }

    @IBAction func setDefault(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
        let defaultVar = "Default"
        Lable.stringValue = defaultVar
    }

    @IBAction func clearText(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
        let clear = " "
        Lable.stringValue = clear
    }

}
```

Then in Interface Builder connect the menu items to **First Responder** (the red cube on the top) of `AppDelegate` and select the methods in the list respectively. The first controller in the responder chain which implemented one of the methods will respond to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug the function when you get the error and see if Lable and Lable.stringValue has been setted; because the error "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" appears when your value is not setted, so the compiler found that as nil and it crash.

Anyway post a screenshot of your storyboard and more code in your ViewController so we can help you better